# ListView cannot scroll to max item inside listview builder

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to put a `Listview` inside `Tab`, here is my script

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: TabBar(
                    controller: _controller,
                    onTap: (index) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedIndex = _controller.index;
                      });
                    },
                    indicatorColor: AppColors.primary,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          "Menu 1",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          "Menu 2",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          "Menu 3",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _controller,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: 1000,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  title: Text(index.toString()),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text("Articles Body"),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text("User Body"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),);
```

As you can i see in tab 1 , i'm trying to create list with `1000  item counts`. But the result it is stuck to list number 14.

[image]

How can i fix it ? thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: because you have specific the height   `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

Answer (score 0):

You have used "NeverScrollableScrollPhysics". This disables the scroll property.
Use "AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics" instead, then you will be able to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You need remove this line from the ListView.builder():

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

to allow scrolling

Comment: Yes i adding it,  because i want to use `SingleChildScrollView` for scrolling the page

Comment: ListView.builder() constructor creates items as they’re scrolled onto the screen. So if you don't enable scroll it can't create more items